# batch convert files using ffmpeg and find -exec and parallel

Tags: ffmpeg, find, gnu-parallel

From another stack exchange post, I came to know that I can batch convert media file with original file name intacted and only change the file extension by using the following

```
find ./ -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i $0 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 ${0/mp4/mp3}' {} \;
```

Since most computers nowadays have multiple cores,  how do I modify the above command, so I can use all 4 cores in the `-exec` part of find thus I can convert 4 media files at the same time?

I know GNU parallel can do something similar, but I don't know how to combine them into one single command.

Thanks in advance

Harv

Comment: Some examples if you search `[ffmpeg] find parallel is:answer`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the filenames, null-terminated to `parallel` like this:

```
find . -name \*.mp4 -print0 | parallel -0 ...
```

You can access parameters in `parallel` via `{}` and you can get filenames without their extensions using `{.}`, so you want:

```
find . -name \*.mp4 -print0 | parallel -0 ffmpeg -i {} ... {.}.mp3
```

Try it with `parallel --dry-run` first to see if it looks right. It will use all cores by default anyway.